# Books/Pieces/Essays about self-worth?

Tags: reference-request, identity, self-cognition

I'm interested in reading some good books/pieces/essays about self-worth (ultimate meaning of life, learning, working, etc).

It's hard to precisely define the topic, but anything you think is relevant is appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Off-topic enough to make me hesitate posting as an answer, but [Theodore Dalrymple on self-esteem and self-respect](http://incharacter.org/features/theodore-dalrymple-on-self-esteem-vs-self-respect/), and why the latter is more desirable.

Comment: Well, 'ultimate meaning of life' is pretty old question in philosophy ;) But you might like Camus' book http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Myth_of_Sisyphus

Comment: Welcome to philosophy.se! Is there any chance we could persuade you to develop or unpack your question to specify the particularly philosophical concern here? (Also, *please* do not cross post questions to multiple SE sites without working it out on chat or meta.)

Answer (score 2):

The first thing that springs to mind is [Marcus Aurelius](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Meditations).

Answer (score 1):

If you are interested in a fictional work that presents a sound philosophical framework for self-worth, I can think of no better one than Ayn Rand's Atlas Shrugged. In it, Rand develops the philosophy of Objectivism as a philosophy to guide an individual's life - with the primacy of the individual as a paramount tenet.

If you are interested in her non-fiction work that presents the case for self-worth and self-realization, I would highly suggest The Virtue of Selfishness.

If you are interested in learning about the one philosopher whom had tremendous influence on Rand, I would point you to Aristotle and his Organon.

Let me know if you'd like suggestions for further study.